# Spring Boot test doesn't load main application config files

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a spring boot application that I'd like to test. For the test, I need to load the whole spring context (just like I'd do when I start the built application).

The problem I'm facing is that the config files (`application.yml` and `bootstrap.yml`) files aren't loaded when I run the test from `maven-failsafe-plugin`. If I run the test from Intellij, everything works fine.

This problem is similar to what happens when I try to reuse a config file from a dependency. I know the loading of config files changed in recent years and I can't seem to ignore the issues I have with it.

Does anybody know how to make spring load config files from the main resources directory when running a maven test?

Comment: I know you answered your own question, but it would be helpful to viewers if you share your test class.

Answer (score 0):

So the behavior of spring I explained in the question is absolutely unchangeable to allow what I'd like to do. I did a lot of digging and it turns out to be [working as intended](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/7a4960d4cada6ca0214157bc5b006fcd0dde8833/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/config/LocationResourceLoader.java#L129), for understandable reasons.

In this specific case, the way this becomes a problem is that the main application (the one we are trying to test here) by default is loaded by that packaged JAR that was created by previous phases of the maven lifecycle.

What we need instead is to load the application by the `target/classes` directory, which is done by adding the following line in the `<configuration>` element of the `failsafe` plugin config: `<classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>`.

This way, the `classpath:application.yml` resolves the `application.yml` from  `src/main/resources` directory without problem.